# What does Actual α mean in G*Power?

Tags: gpower

Can anyone explain what actual α (alpha) means in G*Power?

For input parameters, I choose 0.05 for α err prob, and I get 0.0288167 for Actual α.

Does it mean I should use 0.0288167 instead of 0.05 for the p-value or it is still statistically correct if I use 0.05 for the p-value for rejecting/failure to reject the null hypothesis?

Comment: You need more details. Is this for a discrete test statistic? (e.g. a rank test, a binomial test, etc)

Comment: A *guess* is that you are conducting a test involving a discrete sampling distribution.  In such cases, it is rare for the test to achieve the nominal power (unless you are conducting a randomized test, which I doubt G*Power considers).  Some details would be welcome.